# How to write the Application Settings of Azure Web Job programmatically?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, updates, azure-webjobs, application-settings

I am using the Graph API delta queries to get the last modified users. Now, I need to store the delta token somewhere to reuse that in the next run of the web job.

I don't have access to write into a key vault or blob storage. Is there any way using which, I can store/update this delta token in the application setting of the web job?

**Note: This token will be updated after each run.**

Comment: This question is not related to Microsoft Graph. Rather its related to your application logic, still i can help you on this. I don't think it's possible using webjobs (continuous job) unless you have some web server running where you can fire requests against (say, aspnet core). Alternately think about using Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger. Then you can pass the token in the querystring or in the body of the request and do what you need to do. Just a suggestion to try.